# Java ExecutorService - Task/Callable not cancelling/interrupting

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I am using Java ExecutorService (ThreadPool) to perform a task & update UI while a particular activity is in foreground (visible).

**Problem:**
What i want is when user switches to another activity i want to stop/cancel all the task(whether queued or running). And for this i have to either use ExecutorService shutdown/shutdownNow method or cancel(true) on Future object returned by ExecutorService submit method after checking of Future object status by calling isDone(). This would set the corresponding thread flag for interruption to TRUE which i have to check (Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) in my callable implementation to determine if is interrupted exit the task/thread. Problem is whether i call ExecutorService shutdown method or Future cancel(true) method in both the cases rarely 1 of 10 times it sets the thread interruption flag to TRUE which is eventually leading to memory leaks, etc.

**Code:**

ThreadPool Singleton implementation(cancelAll-to cancel tasks & shutdownExecutor-to shutdown ExecutorService):

```
private static class ThreadPoolManager {

    private ExecutorService executorService;
    private List<Future> queuedFutures;
    private BlockingQueue<Runnable> blockingQueue;

    private static ThreadPoolManager instance;

    private ThreadPoolManager() {
        MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "Threadpool-created(constructor)");
        queuedFutures = new ArrayList<>();
        blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
        executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, blockingQueue);
    }

    static {
        instance = new ThreadPoolManager();
    }

    public static void submitItemTest(Callable<Object> callable) {
        MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "Threadpool-submitted item test");
        if(instance.executorService.isShutdown()){
            instance=new ThreadPoolManager();
        }
        Future future = instance.executorService.submit(callable);
        instance.queuedFutures.add(future);
    }

    public static void submitTestAll(Callable<Object> callable) {
        MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "Threadpool-submitted test all");
        if(instance.executorService.isShutdown()){
            instance=new ThreadPoolManager();
        }
        cancelAll();
        Future future = instance.executorService.submit(callable);
        instance.queuedFutures.add(future);
    }

    public static void cancelAll() {
        MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "Cancelling all future tasks");
        instance.blockingQueue.clear();
        for (Future future : instance.queuedFutures) {
            if (!future.isDone()) {
                boolean cancelled = future.cancel(true);
                MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "Cancelled-" + cancelled);
            }
        }
        instance.queuedFutures.clear();
    }

    public static void shutdownExecutor(){
        MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "Shuttingdown threadpool");
        instance.executorService.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Callable Implementation(normal iteration & if clause to check for interruption):

```
private Callable<Object> getTestAllCallable() {
        return new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() {
                for (int i = 0; i < inbuiltProxyPojoArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                          //someWork

                    } else {
                        MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "ThreadInterrupted-Cancelling");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

Activity/Fragment onStop implementation(for invoking cancel task & shutdown):

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.INFO, "onStop called");
    ThreadPoolManager.cancelAll();
    ThreadPoolManager.shutdownExecutor();
    super.onStop();
}
```

**Update:**

Changes made:

1. Moved from using Runnable instead of callable.
2. Now not using singleton for ExecutorService.

   ```
     private class ThreadPoolManager {

       private ExecutorService executorService;
       private List<Future> queuedFutures;
       private BlockingQueue<Runnable> blockingQueue;

       private ThreadPoolManager() {
           MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "Threadpool-created(constructor)");
           queuedFutures = new ArrayList<>();
           blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
           executorService =getNewExecutorService();
       }

       private ExecutorService getNewExecutorService(){
           return new ThreadPoolExecutor(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, blockingQueue);
       }

       private void submitItemTest(Runnable runnable) {
           MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "Threadpool-submitted item test");
           if(executorService.isShutdown()){
               executorService=getNewExecutorService();
           }
           Future future = executorService.submit(runnable);
           queuedFutures.add(future);
       }

       private void submitTestAll(Runnable runnable) {
           MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "Threadpool-submitted test all");
           if(executorService.isShutdown()){
               executorService=getNewExecutorService();
           }
           cancelAll();
           Future future = executorService.submit(runnable);
           queuedFutures.add(future);
       }

       private void cancelAll() {
           MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "Cancelling all future tasks");
           blockingQueue.clear();
           for (Future future : queuedFutures) {
               if (!future.isDone()) {
                   boolean cancelled = future.cancel(true);
                   MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "Cancelled-" + cancelled);
               }
           }
           queuedFutures.clear();
       }

       private void shutdownExecutor(){
           MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "Shuttingdown threadpool");
           executorService.shutdownNow();
           blockingQueue.clear();
           queuedFutures.clear();
       }
   }
   ```

Found out the culprit but not the solution yet. Following 2 are the implementation of Runnables 1 of which is working (isInterrupted returns true or comes InterupptedException and than task ended) but not other.

Working Runnable(I used it for testing):

```
new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
                    int i=0;
                    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                        try {
                            System.out.println(i);
                            Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG,"Interrupted");
                            return;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Not working(actual code i want to use):

```
new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < inbuiltProxyPojoArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                    } else {
                        MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "Thread Interrupted (Cancelled)");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

And 1 probable solution would be to use variable(boolean) as a interruption flag inside the runnable that i will consider as a last resort but would happy to get to know the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution(Way out):**
So finally i went on to use custom internal flag(boolean)as a Thread interruption flag which will be checked on every iteration by MyRunnable(custom implementation of runnable with custom flag so to have a flag associated with each runnable). Than when cancellation of threads under ExecutorService(ThreadPool) is required i iterate over all Future objects and gets it associated MyRunnable and than set its Interruption Flag(Custom flag) to true which than interrupts/close thread.

**ThreadPoolManager:**

```
private class ThreadPoolManager {

        private ExecutorService executorService;
        private final Map<Future,MyRunnable> queuedFutures;
        private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> blockingQueue;

        private ThreadPoolManager() {
            MyLogger.log(DEBUG, "Threadpool-created(constructor)");
            queuedFutures = new HashMap<>();
            blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
            executorService = getNewExecutorService();
        }

        private ExecutorService getNewExecutorService() {
            return new ThreadPoolExecutor(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, blockingQueue);
        }

        private void submitItemTest(MyRunnable runnable) {
            MyLogger.log(DEBUG, "Threadpool-submitted item test");
            if (executorService.isShutdown()) {
                executorService = getNewExecutorService();
            }
            Future future = executorService.submit(runnable);
            queuedFutures.put(future,runnable);
        }

        private void submitTestAll(MyRunnable runnable) {
            MyLogger.log(DEBUG, "Threadpool-submitted test all");
            if (executorService.isShutdown()) {
                executorService = getNewExecutorService();
            }
            cancelAll();
            Future future = executorService.submit(runnable);
            queuedFutures.put(future,runnable);
        }

        private void cancelAll() {
            MyLogger.log(DEBUG, "ThreadPool: Cancelling all future tasks");
            blockingQueue.clear();
            for (Future future : queuedFutures.keySet()) {
                if (!future.isDone()) {
                    queuedFutures.get(future).continueRunning=false;
                    MyLogger.log(DEBUG, "Cancelled");
                }
            }
            queuedFutures.clear();
        }

        private void shutdownExecutor() {
            cancelAll();
            MyLogger.log(DEBUG, "ThreadPool: Shuttingdown threadpool");
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

**MyRunnable(abstract class that implements Runable):**

```
private abstract class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        boolean continueRunning=true;
    }
```

**MyRunnable(Instance of abstract class MyRunnable):**

```
new MyRunnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           for (int i = 0; i < inbuiltProxyPojoArrayList.size(); i++) {
                 if (continueRunning) {
                        //someWork
                 } else {
                    MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "ThreadPool: Pool Thread Interrupted (closing down)");
                     break;
                 }
            }
            System.out.println("ThreadPool: Test complete");
         }
     };
```

Now, calling threadPoolManager.shutdownExecutor() shutdown/interrupts all the threads currently running.

Answer (score 1):

According to `ExecutorService` documentation, shutting down an executing task is done on a best effort basis.

Therefore, when you call `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` the implementation will **try** to shut down all currently executing tasks. each task will keep running until it reaches a point where it detects it was interrupted.

In order to assure your threads are reaching that point at early stage it is a good idea to add a check in your loop whether the thread is interuppted as follows:

```
Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();
```

By making this call on every iteration your threads will detects the interruption with a short interval from the actual interupption.

And so your modified `Callable` code will look as follows:

```
private Callable<Object> getTestAllCallable() {
    return new Callable<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call() {
            for (int i = 0; i < inbuiltProxyPojoArrayList.size(); i++) {
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    return null;
                }
                if(someCondition) {
                    //someWork
                } else {
                    MyLogger.log(MyLogger.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, "ThreadInterrupted-Cancelling");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

By the way, there is no point in using a `Callable` if you are not intending to return any value from the `call()` method. if you need the parameterized type in your task just  create a parameterized `Runnable` as follows:

```
public class ParameterizedRunnable<T> implements Runnable {
    private final T t;

    public ParameterizedRunnable(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void run() {
        //do some work here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i edited my code now to include what you have stated actually i was already doing that as stated in the problem description but was cleared along with other code which was not relevant.

Comment: I was using callable instead of runnable with thought to get Future object while submitting the callable to ExecutorService and now come to know same can also be done with runnable. Thank you for telling this i will change the code to use runnable.

Comment: It works 1 of 10 times. I also cannot believe as i have already searched alot and studied the docs everywhere it is asking the samething to check for isInterrupted and accordingly do some work or leave.